# Google Maps Marker disappearing after dropping

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to mark some spots on a google map. I am using google maps places javascript api.

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(userlatitude, userlongitude),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapProp);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("midsection"), mapProp);

    var mapPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(-20.997110, 123.375544);

    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: -20.014006,
            lng: 123.421746
        },
        map: map,
        title: 'Mow my lawn',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
```

(if the Long/Lat are invalid, its because I randomly changed it for the purpose of this post)

I can see the marker drop down and bounce once. But then it disappears. I have tried setting the Zindex, changing the display and position type of the div canvas. But nothing I do seems to make the marker stay.

Comment: I can also confirm the marker is "visible" according to the marker object

Comment: Please provide a demo which exhibits the issue

Comment: The posted code works for me after I fix the syntax errors and undefined variables, it doesn't exhibit the reported error. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: i found the error, It was hidden in my custom CSS that another developer put in there. Canvas: display:none

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being hidden in my CSS.
it was just a Canvas: display:none  call